# Finding the shortest cycle containing a vertex in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a connected undirected graph with edges $E$ and verticies $V$ and a vertex $v \in V$, find the length of the shortest cycle containing $v$. The best I could do is $O(|E|*deg(v))$, by trying to choose every edge connected to $v$ as the last edge of the cycle (you just remove that edge $(u, v)$, run BFS from $v$, and the shortest cycle ending with that edge is of length $dist(u, v) + 1$). How could you solve this problem in $O(E)$?

Comment: Could you share more about the background in which you want this question answered?
With such a broad settings, people might wonder if this is merely a homework assignment, for which cstheory.stackexchange is not the right venue (see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tour for suggestions of other venues more appropriate for such questions)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems the problem is actually pretty easy. Just make the BFS tree (or shortest path tree in case of a weighted graph) rooted at $v$, and then for every edge $(a, b)$ not in the tree, if $lca(a, b)=v$, consider it as the shortest cycle (its length being, of course, $dist(v, a) + dist(v, b) + 1$).